# Maps v2 Using Drawable XML for Map Marker

Tags: android, google-maps

Running into an error that is throwing me for a loop.

Background - 
Using Android Google Maps v2 now, I'm trying to add a custom marker to a map. The drawable I'm using is a XML file, that references two other drawables in it (one for the background marker, and then a 'symbol' that's on top of the marker.)

I have not gotten into layer-lists and such in drawables, so my issue may be related to that, OR to how I'm implementing it in the maps.

My drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="34dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/marker_green_blank"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="0dp"/>
    <item
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/marker_symbol_int"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="19dp"
        android:top="4dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

The 'marker_green_blank' is a standard maps marker. The 'marker_synbol_int' is a custom icon to represent the item the marker identifies.

All fine and dandy. The code I'm using to set this to the map marker, is:

```
MarkerOptions opt = new MarkerOptions();
opt.position(mark.location);
opt.title(mark.pid);
opt.snippet(summary);

BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
opts.outHeight = 34;
opts.outWidth = 20;
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.marker, opts);
BitmapDescriptor marker_green_blank = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon);

opt.anchor((float)0.5, 1);
mark.associatedMapMarker = mMap.addMarker(opt);
```

The `mark` object is just a custom holder class that holds information about the location.

When I go to throw a marker on the map, I get the following error on the `addMarker()` call -

```
04-25 14:34:29.709: E/AndroidRuntime(3792): java.lang.NullPointerException:
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()'
    on a null object reference
```

This is obvious, because my `.decodeResource` is returning a null bitmap. Sp, that means my XML is wrong, OR I'm messing something else up.

Pointers on where to start looking? I'd like to take advantage of the layers and such, as there's a total possibility of 45 different markers, and instead of creating 45 bitmaps, having a subset and then using the XML to overlay them would be best.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware that `decodeResource()` works on non-bitmaps. Is there a reason that you are not just using `fromResource()` on `BitmapDescriptorFactory`?

Comment: @CommonsWare `fromResource` in `BitmapDescriptorFactory` can decode only bitmap resources. It will not recognize layer drawable. @Coyttl, you need to change the way you create a Bitmap out of your layer drawable. Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897702/how-to-convert-layerdrawable-to-bitmap . You might have a problem with the bitmap size though, but this is a different story :)

Comment: @CommonsWare - Doing it directly (`BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()`) gives the same result - however, it does produce a BitmapMarker object.

Comment: @Pavel - Thanks! Seeing that, I can figure out how to get the canvas & bitmap - now I need to figure out to use LayerDrawables now, thanks!